# Adobe Air (Flex) with Ajax

Tags: ajax, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I am currently developing a desktop application on flash builder 4.5 . It make uses of Flex.

I found out that there is an Flex-Ajax bridge that can be used to implement Ajax.

But does this work out for desktop application? Cause Ajax is javascript. so i assume that it is only able to use it in web applications.

Can AJAX be implemented in Flex desktop application ?

Comment: Why do you want to do an Ajax call if you are already using Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequest with javascript.